# Access a column from database

Tags: android, database, cursor

Now I want to access an entire column from database and then compare it with some text that I have stored...but I am getting no idea on how to do that..So can someone please help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

Entire column? 
 You mean all the values for a given column accross all records? 
You should iterate the ResultSet obtained and start comparing the values  
 (for example - if you iterate using "rs" object of ResultSet, you should compare:

```
String valueFromDB =  rs.getString("myColumn");
String someTextStored = .... //the text being stored
if (valueFromDB != null) {
   if (someTextStored.equals(valueFromDB) {
   //Comparison succeeded - implement some logic here for handling success
   }
}
```

And the above code should be inside a loop code that iterates over the ResultSet and
uses the "next" method to obtain the next record.

Comment: So see my comment - it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```
public ArrayList<String> getValues(){
  Cursor cursor = null;
  SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
  Log.v("done","getting rows ");

   cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT YourColumnName FROM "+TABLE_NAME, null);
   if(!cursor.moveToFirst()){

   }
   else{
       do {
   list_values.add(cursor.getString(0));

   } while (cursor.moveToNext());

   }
   db.close();
   cursor.close();
  return list_values;
 }
```

Now you are having all the values of a particular column you can compare it from this array list.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use this class...I mean...my database name is Alert and table name is data...so can you tell me how to use it within another method..

Comment: what's the column you need to access and do you have the databasehelper class?

Comment: replace this "SELECT YourColumnName FROM Alert" with the existing "SELECT YourColumnName FROM "+TABLE_NAME in the above post